# UILocalNotification firing repeatative for particular days

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification, repeatingalarm

I am developing alarm application, i want to do the repeat alarm functionality same as there in iOS Alarm Clock application, where we can select repeat option as Every Monday, Every Tuesday,... likewise.

> Example: If i select only Every Monday, Every Wednesday and Every
>   Friday then for all upcoming Monday, Wednesday and Friday the
>   respective Alarm Notification should fire.

i tried:

```
  NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
  NSDateComponents *componentsForFireDate = [calendar components:(NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear |  NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute| NSCalendarUnitSecond | NSCalendarUnitWeekday) fromDate: [dictionaryForAlarm objectForKey:kAlarmSnoozeDate]];

 NSArray *arrayForRepeatDays = @[@"2",@"4",@"6"];

 for (NSString *dayOfWeek in arrayForRepeatDays) {

     [componentsForFireDate setDay:[dayOfWeek integerValue]];
     localNotification.repeatInterval =  NSCalendarUnitWeekOfMonth;;

     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
}
```

but it's not getting fire on the respective days, correct me for this

Thank you in advace!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do code like this:

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
  NSDateComponents *componentsForFireDate = [calendar components:(NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear |  NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute| NSCalendarUnitSecond | NSCalendarUnitWeekday) fromDate: [dictionaryForAlarm objectForKey:kAlarmSnoozeDate]];

 NSArray *arrayForRepeatDays = @[@"2",@"4",@"6"];

 for (NSString *dayOfWeek in arrayForRepeatDays) {

     [componentsForFireDate setWeekday: [dayOfWeek integerValue]] 
     [componentsForFireDate setHour: 10] ; // here you can set hr as per you need
     localNotification.repeatInterval =  NSWeekCalendarUnit;
     localNotification.fireDate=[calendar dateFromComponents:componentsForFireDate];
     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
}
```

I Guess this two like make this working:

```
[componentsForFireDate setWeekday: [dayOfWeek integerValue]] 
localNotification.repeatInterval =  NSWeekCalendarUnit;
```

Comment: Used NSCalendarUnitWeekOfMonth since NSWeekCalendarUnit still not giving the notification, also when i save it, immediately 3 notification gets fired (since kept todays as friday,  Monday and Wednesday is already passed) how to handle this?

Comment: check my updated answer i think you are forget to setting fireDate

Comment: what setHour means exactly?

Comment: it meas the time on that day for example you set monday but in monday which time??? that notification fire??  so for setting time of the day we use hr,min,sec

Comment: sure i will try this